# How to access dom of popup on same page using javascript or chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm working on NetSuite webpage. This page has multiple pop-ups with content data, and each and every popup is opening in a new window of the browser. I want to access the DOM of each popup by Chrome extension and combine that data.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

When you have a handle for the window and cross-origin security rules are met, you can access the document as a property.

```
var win = window.open('https://www.example.com');

// Wait until everything's done loading first
win.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var doc = win.document;
});
```

Comment: Thanks,
I have tried that one also but the window is opening by NetSuite itself. so am not able to access the opening object.

Comment: @SharangKapsikar You have to meet us in the middle. If this doesn't help: Show us some code, what you've attempted to do, and more precisely explain what you want to do.